# Can AI be used for submarine detection?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, ai-design, training-datasets

Recently a lot of work has been done in connection to using AI in the search for extraterestrial life, the [SETI project](https://www.seti.org/press-release/will-machine-learning-help-us-find-extraterrestrial-life).

Could the same methodology be used by the military, in order to detect submarines hiding  in the world's oceans ? Basically the training data sets will have different characteristics,  and the definition of what "relevant signals " are will change, but in principle the fundamental problem is the same, finding relevant signals in an "ocean of noise ".  Is this assessment correct ? Is this avenue of research currently being considered already by the military ? You only need to answer the second question if the answer to the first is yes.

Comment: that would be classified information

Comment: All  the relevant methodology,  data sets, and even source code are open access  @user253751 https://seti.berkeley.edu/ml_gbt/overview.html   , and the translation to a military application is obvious,  to say the least. Maybe it should be classified information,  but at this time I doubt it is. Should I conclude that the answer to my first question is yes ?